# Realm: Delete and Add Object: Object has been deleted or invalidated

Tags: realm, swift3

I have multiple Objects which are not defining a primary key (because our server is handling the primary keys and in offline mode you cant provide a primary key) so i cant use the `update` method if i change data, so i tried the following:

```
func updateTest() {
    let myObjects = realm.objects(MyObject.self).filter("id = 1"); // id is NOT the primary key from realm!

    var myObject: MyObject!;

    if (myObjects.count > 0) {
        myObject = myObjects[0];
    }

    if (myObject != nil) {
        try! self.realm.write() {
            self.realm.delete(self.myObject);
        }

        // modify
        self.myObject.status = "waiting";

        try! self.realm.write() {
            self.realm.add(self.myObject); // crash
        }
    }
}
```

But when I want to add the object now i get:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception: 'RLMException', reason: 'Object has been deleted or invalidated.'
```

So several questions here:

**Is there any possibility to select only a single result?**

**Is there any possibility to update an object by providing a field name which is not the primary key?**

**How can i delete and readd an object without getting this error?**

**would it maybe make sense to implement a dummy primary key?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do can be accomplished like this:

```
func updateTest() {
    guard let myObject = realm.objects(MyObject.self).filter("id = 1").first else {
        return
     }

    try! realm.write {
        myObject.status = "waiting"
    }
}
```

> Is there any possibility to select only a single result?

You can use Swift's `guard let` to bind the first element in the result set to a variable if one exists, using the `else` clause for your fallback if the object cannot be found. In this case I simply return from the function.

> Is there any possibility to update an object by providing a field name which is not the primary key?

Yes. Perform a query to locate the object in question, then change its properties however you wish.

> How can I delete and readd an object without getting this error?

You cannot delete and re-add an object. There's no way to resurrect a deleted object. It's not necessary to do this to get the behavior you're after.

> Would it maybe make sense to implement a dummy primary key?

It's not necessary to get the behavior you're after.